# How to get long movie clips from iCloud to Google Drive

Tags: icloud, google-apps

What is the easiest way of getting large movies (20 minutes) from my iPhone/iCloud to my Google Drive account for work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use your computer as an intermediate step.

If you open 2 windows, one open to iCloud Drive, the other to Google Drive, then you can drag from one to the other … but all the files will go via your computer to get from one to the other. Depending on available space you may have to do it in stages.

If you're working from web access for both, then you will have to download, then upload, as two separate steps for each file.

Comment: Why couldn't he/she just use the Google Drive App on her phone?

Comment: Phone/computer - it still has to go via the device.